# How to force StrToInt, StrToIntDef to ignore hex values?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle, string-conversion

I have variable that can hold either a string or an integer. So, I use `If StrToIntDef(Value) > 0` to decide either I am processing strings or integers. But this fails, when the string starts with 'x' or 'X'. I assume because it thinks it's a hex number and converts it to integer:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Value:integer;
  Str:string;
begin

  Str:='string';
  Value:=StrToIntDef(Str,0); // Value = 0  OK

  Str:='xa';
  Value:=StrToIntDef(Str,0); // Value = 10 - NOT OK! Shuold be 0!

  Str:='XDBA';
  Value:=StrToIntDef(Str,0); // Value = 3514 - NOT OK! Shuold be 0!

end;
```

**How can I make conversion function to ignore hex values?**

Comment: Just check if the string starts with `'x'` or `'X'` and then make the check fail, before you pass it to `StrToIntDef()`.

Comment: Not good enough, also need to check `$`. And presumably also `0x`. I'd consider validating that each character is a digit, `0..9`.

Comment: @David: true. Also check for `'$'`.

Comment: No way do to it, this is by design. Write your own implementation.

Comment: Also `0$` will trigger hex notation.

Comment: @LURD: That's weird. I'd expect only `0x`, `0X` or `$` to be valid, but not `x`, `X`, or `0$`. If that is the case, the routine is slightly deficient.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, my guess is that it simplifies the code to identify hex notation. Otherwise, only Emba can tell.

Comment: `'0'` is invalid integer by the other logic anyway.

Comment: Just checked out of curiousity - non-lain unicode digit characters (`٤٢`, ``) don't work.

Comment: @FreeConsulting: I don't understand. By what "other" logic would `'0'` be an invalid integer representation?

Comment: "*I have variable that can hold either a string or an integer*" - are you using an `(Ole)Variant` for that? If not, why not? "*I use `If StrToIntDef(Value) > 0` to decide either I am processing strings or integers*" - first, you should be using `TryStrToInt()` instead of `StrToIntDef()`. But really, if a string happens to contain a valid numeric representation, you are SOL. An `(Ole)Variant` carries information about the data type it is holding. You don't need to guess, you can query that info directly, using `VarType()`, `VarIsType()`, `VarIsStr()`, `VarIsNumeric()`, etc

Comment: @Rudy, OP's wacky logic expressed as `isInt := StrToIntDef(Value, 0) > 0`

Comment: I read these values from text files and as I do not needs to check these so often, I thing (OLE)Variant could be overkill... well, I never used Variant types and they just seem a bit too much for my simple process - is either a number or not in string value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think to be on the safe side you should validate that each character is a digit.

```
function StrToIntDefDecimal(const S: string; Default: Integer): Integer;
var
  C: Char;
begin
  for C in S do
    if ((C < '0') or (C > '9')) and (C <> '-') then
    begin
      Result := Default;
      exit;
    end;
  Result := StrToDef(S, Default);
end;
```

However, if you simply wish to detect whether or not the string is numeric, then you can do so like this:

```
function IsDecimalInteger(const S: string): Boolean;
var
  C: Char;
begin
  for C in S do
    if ((C < '0') or (C > '9')) and (C <> '-') then
    begin
      Result := False;
      exit;
    end;
  Result := True;
end;
```

Even this is imperfect because it will allow a value like `'1-2'`. But I am sure that you could modify the code to only accept `'-'` as the first character.

Note also that your existing test for a number, `StrToIntDef(Value) > 0`, will treat zero or negative numbers as strings. Is that really what you intend.

Comment: I don't see anything in the OP's code that tests for `> 0`.

Comment: @KenWhite It's tucked away in the second sentence of the first paragraph.

Comment: @KenWhite, OP treats a value `'0'` as invalid integer, thus as "string".

Comment: Ah, I looked at the code itself. Thanks. @Free: Not related to what I wrote at all.

Comment: Great! Thank you, I can make function that checks for `string or integers > 0` and for `strings or integer <> 0`.